# Getting Rid of Internal Bar Lines in a Bar Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing a basic bar plot in ggplot2 in R.

The code is:

```
  ggplot(shootings,aes(x=Year,y= Injured))+geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="#CC6666",colour="black")+ggtitle("Injured")
```

It renders like this:

[image]

Questions:

1. Are the bars separated by an internal horizontal line stacked or overlapping?
2. Assuming they are stacked (for example, the bar at year 1984 represents 2 incidents - one with a total of 19 injured and one with a total of 1 injured for a grand total of 20), how do I get rid of the horizontal line at value y = 19 so I can display a single bar with value of 20?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

@Didzis Elferts  Strangely when I run your code (with an addition to remove the legend) I get this:

[image]

2 weird things:  It has strange aesthetics (which I suppose I can certainly modify) but the sum doesn't appear to be working (1984 now shows only as a total of 19 - not 20.  I tried to put in x, y values but it didn't work).  Do they need to be put in?  Thanks.

Edit 2:

@Didzis Elferts  Your modified answer (with stat_summary) with my code:

```
ggplot(shootings,aes(Year,Injured))+ stat_summary(fun.y=sum,geom="bar",colour="black",fill="#CC6666",show.legend = FALSE)+ ggtitle("Injured")
```

Worked perfectly!

[image]

Comment: Nope. Doesn't do it.  Plus the appearance of the historgram IMHO looks more crisp when you have a black outline and colored fil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to sum the values of `Injured` for each year, you can use `stat_summary()` with `geom="bar"` and set `fun.y=sum`

```
ggplot(shootings,aes(Year,Injured))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=sum,geom="bar",fill="#CC6666",colour="black")+
  ggtitle("Injured")
```

Comment: Thanks.  Please see edit in the question.  Could not put adequate response in comment.

Comment: @Windstorm1981 It is impossible to solve your new problem because I don't have your data. With my data it worked without problems

Comment: @Windstorm1981 Also, did you use `stat_summary()` (I updated my answer).

Comment: Thank you.  I will investigate further on my end.  This is not the first time I've seen the same code work differently across RStudio.

Comment: Your modified solution worked perfectly!  Thank you!